# How to use my native language in django cms with zinnia

Tags: django-cms, zinnia

I try to use Zinnia with Django-CMS but I can't figure out how could i use my native language in it. I know it's translated, there is a directory in zinnia's locale folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you need to have the LANGUAGE_CODE setting to your native language and activated the Django i18n mechanism.

Then if Zinnia has a translation for your language, it will be used.

If not, you can contribute on the Transifex page for adding your translation, which will be included in the next releases.

https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/django-blog-zinnia/resource/djangopo/

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you tell me how to avoid this language part in uri like "/en/"?